# building Debian package without associated packages that are bundled together

Tags: debian, compiling, dpkg

When I am building a debian package, often many related packages that are bundled together are being build, and also the `foo-dbgsym-*` versions and `foo-doc` packages.

For example, even relatively simple package such as `make`, will build additional packages:

```
make-dbgsym_4.2.1-1.2_amd64.deb
make-guile-dbgsym_4.2.1-1.2_amd64.deb
make-guile_4.2.1-1.2_amd64.deb
make_4.2.1-1.2_amd64.deb
```

Can I tell the build system to only build `make` and not `make-guile` ?

Here is the process that I am using for building the package:

```
apt-get source make
cd make*
dpkg-buildpackage --build=binary --no-sign
```

Is there a general process how I can specify which packages I want to build?

Make is a simple example, but larger packages build many versions of package which I am not interested in, which need dependent libraries installed, and the build process takes longer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dbgsym` packages can be disabled using [the `noautodbgsym` build option](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/debhelper/debhelper.7#Supported_flags_in_DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS):

```
DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=noautodbgsym dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

It’s also possible to build only architecture-dependent or architecture-independent packages, by changing the `--build` option on `dpkg-buildpackage`.

Other than that, there’s no generalised way of picking and choosing packages to build and dependencies to install. In particular, build dependencies aren’t tied to the binary packages they are relevant for.

Some packages support [build profiles](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildProfileSpec); you can determine that by looking for `Build-Profiles` and/or angle-bracketed dependencies in `debian/control`. On such packages, `dpkg-buildpackage`’s `-P` option selects the appropriate profile(s), sometimes in combination with a build option. For example, on packages with a `nocheck` profile,

```
DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=nocheck dpkg-buildpackage -Pnocheck
```

will skip the testing-related build-dependencies (if any) and skip running the tests.

In fact, the latest version of the `make` package purports to provide a `noguile` build profile, so it should be possible to skip Guile with

```
dpkg-buildpackage -Pnoguile -us -uc
```

except that [the profile definition is incomplete](https://bugs.debian.org/993944).

It is always possible to edit `debian/control` to remove irrelevant packages, and `debian/rules` to remove irrelevant build steps.